# What does >?= mean in c++?

Tags: c++

I found this line of code in topcoder.

```
m>?=y*s[i];
```

This line probably is equivalent to `m = max(m, y * s[i]);`. But I can't understand how this line works. Especially what does the operator `>?=` do? I searched here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence but couldn't find any such operator.

Comment: This shouldn't compile. `?` is only used in the ternary operator and that requires a colon to form an expression. Please post a minimal example showing how does this compile.

Comment: It doesn't compile. http://cpp.sh/97r4

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have a link to where you found this?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz `?` is also used in [digraphs and trigraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) but this doesn't appear to be one of those either.

Comment: How is that line equivalent to `m = max(m, y * s[i]);`

Comment: @vishal it isn't, that was just a guess by a very confused questioner.

Comment: My guess is that this non-standard code is understood by some exotic compiler with some extension. Maybe `a >?= b` is a short-hand form of `a = (a > b ? a : b)` or something similar.

Comment: The syntax seems somewhat intuitive, resembling "m += ...". I'd expect it to behave like "m = (m > xyz) ? m : xyz". Or the other way around, so either `max` or `min`. It's not in any standard, of course.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I found this in the editorial for the SIngle Round Match 322 of Topcoder. This is the link: http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&rm=249964&rd=10002&pm=6804&cr=7390224